# Character limit on typing/pasting hex into numericupdown

Tags: c#, winforms, hex, numericupdown

Im trying to build a winform at the moment. I need a box to enter a hexidecimal byte offset (i.e. should be capable of holding a 64 bit number).

I had thought a numericupdown would work but it seems to have a 32 bit limit. Is there a way around this or a more suitable approach somebody could suggest?

Update:

The 32 bit (8 character) limit refers to typing/pasting a value into the box.

Comment: Why has this been down-voted? There isn't even a comment (besides this one.) As the answer shows this is not a trivial issue.

Answer (score 0):

NumericUpDown.Value is a decimal

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

10^28 is about 2^100 (so 100 bits for mantissa) so 64 bits are ok

If you try this piece of code on a just created numericupdown works fine...

```
        numericUpDown1.Maximum = UInt64.MaxValue;
        numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Maximum;
```

EDIT: if you set the flag for hex you can't use UInt64 but only Int64. I missed it... Anyway, Int64 is ok.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go when Im back on my machine later.

Comment: This works, but typing/pasting into the box only seems to allow an 8 character (32 bit) value. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, nothing wrong. I had a look and the method ParseEditText probably internally works with Int32 numbers. You can see it because if you call the method while the textbox contains more than an Int32 the Value property returns the old value and the text box is set to the old value. Is the same behaviour that you can see if paste characters different from hex digits (not type because the textbox rejects it).

Comment: Any thoughts on a way around this? Ive had a go at directly capturing text from the text box, using a long.parse and sending straight back into the value. It half works but still wont let me physically type past 8 characters. I also tried inheriting the NumericUpDown in a user control and changing the Int32 to a long.parse but it either didnt work or I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: I'm using framework 4 and I can paste anything and also typing anything (but on lostfocus it truncates what I typed probably because of ParseEditText). Are you loosing data in Paste or after some other operation? Because probably the ParseEditText is called often. I had another look and probably you need to override several methods to avoid the ParseEditText problem (ParseEditText is not overridable :( that's so bad). If I will need that probably I will write a user control.

Comment: Sorry i should post some code really but Im away from my machine for a few days. As is, without me fumbling about in the dark, the number if typed/pasted over the limit will revert to its previous value on loss of focus or incrementing via the spinner. Sending the typed text (via the long.parse) directly into the numericupdown1.value did allow it to hold the value once pasted but typing was still an issue I havent been able to bypass.